# Access - If form maximized then allow scrollbars

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have found this API that checks whether form is maximized :
[ACC2000: How to Determine If a Form Is Maximized or Minimized](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210190)

Now I want to use this API to allow Scrollbars on form, If It's maximized. Problem is that when It get's maximized, scrollbars are not visible until I click on some control in detail section. Same way when form is restored - scrollbars don't dissapear until I click on some control. Any way to fix this ?

I tried this (I have to click Field1 after this code, focus not working):

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Maximized = True Then
Me.ScrollBars = 2
Else
Me.ScrollBars = 0
End If

Me.Field1.SetFocus

End Sub
```

and this (when seting Me.TimerInterval=0 nothing happens, otherwise It's working but keeps triggering timer event):

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
If Maximized = True Then
Me.ScrollBars = 2
Else
Me.ScrollBars = 0
End If

Me.Field1.SetFocus
Me.TimerInterval = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed, in resize event code works just fine:

```
If Maximized = True Then
Me.ScrollBars = 2
Else
Me.ScrollBars = 0
End If

Me.Field1.SetFocus
```